# .htaccess правило для subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть ссылка:

**www.site.com/category/test.html**

**1.** www.site.com/category/test.html - отображаем содержимое страницы .html

**2.** www.site.com/category/ - делаем редирект на root сайта

Т.е при обращении к поддиректории, нужно перебрасывать на главную сайта, но если указывать имя файла .html тогда отображать его.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/category/$
RewriteRule .* http://www.site.com
```

Comment: После данного правила при обращении к директории в урле, отображается локальный патч ! типа www.site.com/var/www/username/....  но только в том случае если ставить слеш www.site.com/category/ если в конце без слеша, то нормально

Comment: @webstackoverload что такое «локальный патч»? Данное правило отлично работает в рамках вашего вопроса. Смотрите какие еще у вас манипуляции с урлами в конфигах, движке, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Есть ещё простой вариант — в подкаталогах (/category/) создать **index.php** c 301-редиректом на главную. В **.htaccess** же написать

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```